# MS Azure Webrole - How to specify web root drive storage size

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm working on very large and complex enterprise web application to be hosted in azure. In noticed that the web root is located on E drive. I also noticed that C: drive is 490GB size. But interestingly the size of web root on E drive is only 1GB.

is there any way to either specify the drive you want to  install e.g. C: or specify the size of the drive while deploying?

I also checked that all M,Large etc. VM Size have same storage size for E:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** specify the location of **webroot**! Also, when designing any applications to run in a Platform-as-a-Service (such as Azure Web Role), you have to abstract data storage. You shall never ever write anything but **temporary** data to local drives. For all application's data you must use [Azure blob Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/). And for large temporary files, you can use [Local Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx) as already prompted by sharptooth.

PaaS is a `stateless` service. Meaning that if a hardware failure occurs, a new VM will be immediately created for you and the deployment package will be used to initialize it. Also, if an update of the GuestOS is required, the VM will be taken down and re-instantiated with the new image and original deployment packages. And so on. Meaning that **anything** you've written to the local file system will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You don't control the drives sizes directly - you get whatever Microsoft promised for the VM of your choice. You also don't control where the role payload gets deployed.

However it looks like you want some extra disk space for deploying the dependencies of your stuff an Azure and 1 gigabyte on drive E is not enough for you. If that's the case you can use ["local resources"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx). Those can easily be many gigabytes in size. So you can split your application in parts and move the largest parts into "local resource".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the location of the webroot to another drive.  The good news is as long as **you don't write files at run time to the approot** you don't have to worry about running out of space.

When your web role is deployed the following calculation is used to determine the size of the E drive.

> The %approot% drive size is calculated as , or 1.5 GB, **whichever is larger**. The size of your VM has no bearing on this calculation. (The VM size only affects the size of the temporary C: drive.)

Therefore there will always be enough room to hold all the files in your applications package

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configuration-and-management-faq#why-does-the-drive-on-my-cloud-service-vm-show-very-little-free-disk-space