# Increasing the size of the Siteroots drive in my Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a `Cloud Service` with a `Web Role`.  The default SITEROOT drive is too small for all the files I need.  Now, I have tried updating the "`VM Size`" in the `Configuration` of the Cloud Service, but that increases the size of OTHER drives on the Cloud Service VM.

**Q: How do I make the SITEROOT's drive larger?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713882/ms-azure-webrole-how-to-specify-web-root-drive-storage-size). In general, there is no control on the size of the drives.